How many three-digit natural numbers $\overline{abc}$ such that $a, b, c$ are the sides of an isosceles triangle?

How many three-digit natural numbers $\overline{abc}$ such that $a, b, c$ are the sides of an isosceles triangle?

I got the correct answer, but it took me a while. Below is my final solution (also my thinking process).  I hope to receive some advice (e.g. how I could have reasoned more efficiently to get to the final answer). Thank you!

If the isosceles triangle is equilateral, $a = b = c \in \{1, 2, 3,..., 9\} \implies$ There are $9$ such triangles.
If the isosceles triangle is not equilateral, let $x, y, y$ be its sides. We have:
\begin{equation}
\begin{cases}
1 \leq x \leq 9 \\
1 \leq y \leq 9 \\
x < 2y \\
x \ne y
\end{cases}
\iff
\begin{cases}
1 \leq x \leq \min(9, 2y - 1) \\
2 \leq 2y \leq 18 \\
x \ne y
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
• $y = 1,$ there are $0$ possible value for $x.$
• $y = 2,$ there are $2$ possible values for $x.$
• $y = 3,$ there are $4$ possible values for $x.$
• $y = 4,$ there are $6$ possible values for $x.$
• $y \in \{5, 6, 7, 8, 9\},$ there are $8$ possible values for $x.$
Select one position in $\overline{abc}$ for $x: \dbinom{3}{1}$
The total number of $\overline{abc}  = 9 + \dbinom{3}{2}( 0 + 2 + 4 + 6 + 5 \cdot 8) = 165.$

Looks to me like a reasonable way to go about it.

@GerryMyerson Thank you!
